# Passing command to shell with "&" operator fails to open app, ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gvim

Hi I open files in the same folder the current file in the buffer in a couple of GUI apps (inkscape and libreoffice calc) on a regular basis from within Gvim  as part of my workflow .
Inkscape is the main problem:

`!inkscape ~/filepath-to-graphics/foobar.skg &`

Produces the  `Type ENTER or command to continue` message in vim. Using no `&` operator does open the file but does not open it in the background rendering vim unusable till I type Ctrl C to abort the process.
Using `&&` produces the same result. All the described commands for opening the GUI apps work as expected when entered from a terminal.

Libreoffice opens as expected from within using either no  operator or `&&`. It still opens a process in the background and vim is free to continue. Using `&` produces the same result as inkscape.

The above procedures worked as expected in Ubuntu 18.04 . I have recently done fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 . I brought my ~/.vimrc over from that installation.
I would like to be able to open the apps (again) without moving from the buffer window I am currently in because I have very long filepaths and can save lots of typing by using the `%%` command to get all of the filepath .
I have included and excerpt from the vim log file produced by using the tip here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025615/is-there-a-vim-runtime-log
from the point where the shell is called to execute the command to the end of the file.

```
   :!inkscape ~/long_filepath_to_graphics-file.svg &
Calling shell to execute: "inkscape ~/long_filepath_to_graphics-file.svg &"
Executing CursorHold Autocommands for "*"
autocommand call xolox#misc#cursorhold#autocmd()
vim-misc 1.17.6: Checking handler xolox#session#auto_save_periodic with interval 60 and last run 1610075845 ..
vim-misc 1.17.6: Running handler xolox#session#auto_save_periodic ..
Executing CursorHold Autocommands for "*"
autocommand call xolox#misc#cursorhold#autocmd()
vim-misc 1.17.6: Checking handler xolox#session#auto_save_periodic with interval 60 and last run 1610075920 ..
vim-misc 1.17.6: Running handler xolox#session#auto_save_periodic ..
Executing CursorHold Autocommands for "*"
autocommand call s:clear_message()
Executing BufUnload Autocommands for "*"
autocommand call s:OnBufferUnload()
Executing VimLeavePre Autocommands for "*"
autocommand call xolox#session#auto_save()
autocommand call xolox#session#auto_unlock()
Writing viminfo file "/home/alasdair/.viminfo"
Executing VimLeave Autocommands for "*"
autocommand call s:OnVimLeave()
```

Comment: Is this just about how to prevent the `Type ENTER or command to continue` message?

Comment: No that's not the issue. The issue is the the application (inkscape) is not opening in a background process with the operators && after the command  `:! inkscape ~/file.skg &&` but is run from the shell in vim preventing any further work in vim with out killing the process with Ctrl-c . using the command `:! inkscape ~/file.skg &` just produces the message `Type ENTER or command to continue` but does not open inkscape.